# How to examine the fast output of rsync

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync for backup about 100GB files and directories. My command is

```
sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

However, the output for each file goes up so quickly and there are so many files, that I worry if there are some errors I cannot catch. So I wonder how you would catch any errors during backup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redirect the error stream to a file that you can read later. The verbose output goes to standard output whereas errors go on standard error.

```
sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2 2>rsync-errors
echo $?
cat rsync-errors
```

Alternatively, instead of using verbose mode, use `--progress` or `-P` to just see a progress indicator, that way you will see error messages scroll by. It is possible that they'll scroll too fast if there are a lot of them.

In any case, check that the return status of `rsync` is 0, indicating that there were no errors.

Comment: Thanks! (1) I have run my command. How shall I get the return status? (2) I have too many files to copy, and it takes hours. I cannot stare at the screen all the time. So the way of using progress may not work. But redirect the error stream to a file is a good idea. (3) I actually ran again with `sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2 > log_rsync`. If I am correct, the error stream will still go to the terminal not the file?

Comment: @Tim 1) `echo $?` (0 means success). 3) Yes, redirecting either stdout or stderr will leave you with just the errors on the terminal or in the log file.

Comment: What does `?` mean?

Comment: `$?` gives exit status of the last command.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles!  I realize that verbose mode severely slows down `rsync`. If I don't specify `-vv` or `-v`, will the error if any still be printed on terminal? What would you suggest to get the necessary output information while not slow it down as much as possible?

Comment: @Tim Without `-v`, you will only see error messages.

Comment: Will only error messages be okay and sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2 |& tee rsync.output
```

The file 'rsync.output' will contain your output.